# How to import a resource when using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, xml, spring-mvc, castle-windsor, spring.net

I'd like to hold my components in a separate xml file for production, development etc etc. Can this be done with Castle Windsor?

When using spring.net, i can use

```
<springDestinations>
      <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
        <import resource="file://~/Config/blablabla.xml"/>
      </objects>
    </springDestinations>
```

Using Castle Windsor, i have the following components

```
<components>
  <component id="Retriever" service="Model.Services.Remote.IRetriever, Model" type="Model.Services.Remote.Retriever, Model">
    <parameters>
      <resourceUrl>http://localhost:8888/Service.svc/</resourceUrl>          
    </parameters>
  </component>
</components>
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`<include>` elements](http://castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/includes.html) and [conditional registration](http://castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/defines.html) in your XML configuration.